# DND kit sensors testing using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, dnd-kit

I am trying to write unit tests for setting up of [DND kit](https://docs.dndkit.com/) sensors (mouse, touch, keyboard). So basically, at this point, I just want a test that those sensors have been set up correctly. Does anyone has any idea how to do this in React using Jest? I would really appreciate any help, Thanks!